# Highstock and null values

Tags: highcharts

I have a linear chart with null values as you can see in the first link.
For example my value for the 18th may is calculated between the 18 and the 19.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/29WKr/2/`
```

For the 20th I've a NULL value but I'd like to have a line between the 19 and the 20 like the second picture. I don't want a value for the 20th (I could put the same value as the 19 and have my line but in that case we don't see there is a hole) like here:

```
 `http://jsfiddle.net/29WKr/3/`
```

In fact I need something like the second chart but with keeping the null value and have a line.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Set `connectNulls: true` see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/29WKr/4/ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I put this option I don't see if there are null values because the line is continuous.
I just want a line between the the 19 and the 20th. and not between 20 and 21th because the value is null

Comment: I was looking for an option like point width and define it as 1 day in my example

Comment: So you want line to 20th, but you don't want to add point there, right? In that case it's just impossible.

Comment: Yes that's right because my value for 19th may is calculated between 19 and 20th.

Comment: So thanks for you answers, but if it's impossible I'll try to find an other way.